# Excel cannot define a List in Data Validation from an existing Table Name and Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

In cell `O2` below, I want to propose a drop down list box of values which are defined in the column `Group` of the table `Table2` (this table is located in the columns L and M), but I get a generic error message "There's a problem with this formula" when I enter `=Table2[Group]`. I know this syntax works when I use it directly inside a cell (for instance `=MATCH("Feature",Table2[Group],0)` returns `2`).

(you can see at the end of the question a screenshot of what I want to obtain)

[image: Excel Data Validation]

The syntax seems to be partially accepted by Excel, because as you can see in the screenshot above, it's able to locate correctly the values in the column `Group`, because they appear in a dotted-green box.

For information, below is the name of the table, defined as a Table, and see that it appears in the Name manager:

[image: Excel Table name and Name manager]

**My question: do you know if there's a solution to get the list of values by referring to the Table Name and Column?**

The final result I expect (that I can successfully get with Source like `Bug,Feature,Not urgent,Quick bug,Removed,To remove,UX bug`, or via a Name created manually like `=myname`, but not with Table/Column names):

[image: Excel cell possible values via Drop Down List Box]

NB: my Excel version is [image: Excel 365 version 16.0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Englobe your table with INDIRECT function. Your source will be:

```
=INDIRECT("Table2[Group]")
```

[image]